# Duplicate element in array not allowed? Error: ngRepeat:dupes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I came across this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myShoppingList", []); 
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.products = ["Milk", "Bread", "Cheese"];
    // If I push a duplicate here, it will crash
});
</script>

<div ng-app="myShoppingList" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in products">{{x}}<span ng-click="removeItem($index)">×</span></li>
  </ul>
  <input ng-model="addMe">
  <button ng-click="addItem()">Add</button>
</div>

<p>Click the little x to remove an item from the shopping list.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

which runs OK. However, if I push a duplicate element in the array, like this:

```
$scope.products.push("Milk");
```

the application will crash. Why is that?

---

1. Same behavior if I statically initialize an array with a duplicate.
2. Sets are with curly brackets, so I don't get this.

Comment: do this ng-repeat="x in products track by $index", angular ng-repeat does not allow duplicate

Comment: See [AngularJS Error Reference - ngRepeat:dupes](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes)

Comment: I see CharlieNg! Thank you @georgeawg, interesting link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are some duplicates in your array, you need to track them. Use `track by $index` in your `ng-repeat` like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="x in products track by $index">
```

This should solve your problem. For more information you can look through docs for `ng-repeat` ([Tracking and Duplicates](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)).

Comment: So the problem is not the array but the `ng-repeat`? I would like an explanation though, why this happens' why my `ng-repeat` crashes and yours does not?

Comment: @gsamaras, yes, if there are some duplicates in your array, you need to track them. For more information you can look through docs for `ng-repeat` ("Tracking and Duplicates"): https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat